# Scale SVG shape to fit to contents, where contents includes foreignObject

Tags: html, xhtml, svg

Is there a way - preferably without using JavaScript - to put some HTML contents into an SVG shape using `foreignObject`, such that the SVG shape will auto-resize (or scale) to fit its contents?

I.e. something very vaguely like this pseudocode example, but valid, and functional in the way I've described:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<svg xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="SCALE_TO_FIT_CONTENTS" height="SCALE_TO_FIT_CONTENTS" fill="gray">
    <foreignobject width="100%" height="100%">
      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div>Some HTML text</div>
      </body>
    </foreignobject>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: have you tried with 100% and height 100% of the parent

Comment: Care to give an example as an answer? If it works as I've described, I'll gladly mark it as accepted.

Comment: @sampablokuper what have you tried?

Comment: @Duopixel a few things, none successful. See example above, for instance, which is partly based on Waqar Alamgir's suggestion.

Comment: Well, his suggestion was spot-on http://jsfiddle.net/WDFgF/

Comment: @Duopixel, in your jsfiddle example, the parent element does not auto-resize to fit its contents. So while it may answer somebody's question, I'm afraid it does not answer my question. PS. I've also now clarified my question slightly to reduce the risk of a possible misunderstanding.

Comment: I guess what I'm after is a way to make SVG shapes behave like DIV elements, with the difference that because they are SVG shapes, they need not have rectangular borders.

Comment: Btw I've had similar issue and `foreignObject { overflow: visible; }` did it for me. I gave up scaling since there was no actual use of it.

Answer (score 5):

without using javascript, there is no possible way you could do that. In fact, the SVG shapes cannot be used as containers. But, I hope this is what you're asking for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFun(){
        var w = document.getElementById("myDiv").scrollWidth;
        document.getElementById("myRect").setAttribute("width",w);
    }
</script>
<svg xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onload="myFun()">
    <rect id="myRect" x="10" y="10" width="0" height="100" fill="red"></rect>

        <foreignObject x="10" y="10" position="absolute" width="100%" height="100%">
            <div id="myDiv" style="display: inline-block;">Some HTML text that resizes its SVG container</div>
        </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick would be to wrap everything in a `<g>` element and then measure that element using [`getBBox()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) and then the height of the inner content is known, and could be used to modify the parent **SVG** element's height.

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var bbox = svg.firstElementChild.getBBox();

svg.setAttribute("height", bbox.height + "px");
```

```html
<svg>
  <g>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="200px" fill="red"></rect>
        <foreignObject x="10" y="500" position="absolute" width="100%" height="100%">
            <div id="myDiv" style="display: inline-block;">Some HTML text that resizes its SVG container</div>
        </foreignObject>
        <text dy='500'>aaaaaaaaa</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```